# Print a particular array using query with a json

Tags: jquery, json, charts

I have a json of this format.

```
{
"data" : 
    {
        "names" : [ ["alex","brian","charles","darwin"],

        "marks" : {
            "math" : ["5", "7", "0", "5"],
            "science" : ["8", "5", "2", "3"],
            "french" : ["3", "10", "7", "10"],
            "commerce" : ["9", "6", "12", "10"],
            "total" : ["25", "28", "21", "30"]

        }

    }
```

}

How do i print only the values of total by using the jquery each statement..as i have to pass the values as an array to a chart dynamically.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have an extra `[` character after `"names"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access that array at `yourJsonVariable.data.marks.total`. If you are to pass the values as an array, there is no need to iterate over them with `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

say your json data is `jsondata`

use

```
console.log(jsondata.data.marks.total)
```

this should give you the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on the answers, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eUYvy/) for an example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var jsonData = {
    "data": {
        "names": ["alex", "brian", "charles", "darwin"],

            "marks": {
            "math": ["5", "7", "0", "5"],
                "science": ["8", "5", "2", "3"],
                "french": ["3", "10", "7", "10"],
                "commerce": ["9", "6", "12", "10"],
                "total": ["25", "28", "21", "30"]



        }
    }
};

alert(jsonData.data.marks.total);
});
```